# Is it possible to change Eclipse's window color (grey to something else)?

Tags: eclipse, osx-lion, background-color

I am using OS X Lion and bought a Dell monitor last night.

A few minutes ago, I found that with the Eclipse's default window background color, the color trembles like a fluorescent light. That color was (233,233,233) and I found the color makes that part of the screen tremble in every case. I mean, if I set the desktop color to that, the desktop trembles.

I had installed Windows on the same Mac, so I booted up with Windows 7, but (233,233,233) did not make the screen tremble. Maybe it is because of the Lion OS.

Now, with the Eclipse's background trembling, it is really annoying to write codes. I investigated the preferences, but I could not find any option to change the window background color. How can I do this?

If the color is tied to the system preferences, how can I change the system color for that? I could not change any option in the System Preferences dialogue either.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of text editors via Preferences -> "Text Editors". Though, I'm not sure whether it will be any prettier than what you see today...

[image]